# I'm having trouble with Geolocation

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to get this Geolocation script to work however for myself I always end up getting "Unable to retrieve your location". Here is the link to the web page that has a live result exactly how I want it. I've tried copying the jsfiddle to a blank one with all the same HTML, JS, and CSS. However I can't make it work. Do I need an API key or something. If you need me to elaborate I'm more than glad to, thank you for your time.

Here is the link to the live result(scroll down after clicking)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

https://jsfiddle.net/yotzincastrejon/bwujL03d/

```
HTMl
<p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Show my location</button></p>
<div id="out"></div>

JS
    function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  }

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your own code?

Comment: The title of the question should describe the problem you're facing, not your experience while trying to solve it. Also, we need to see the related code.

Comment: What browsers have you tried it with?

Comment: I've tried it in chrome, using the example from the first link it works fine but when I copy the code and try it myself nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working now https://jsfiddle.net/bwujL03d/1/

You need to place this code in the head ( before the page gets loaded )

```
function geoFindMe() {
var output = document.getElementById("out");

if (!navigator.geolocation){
output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
return;
}

function success(position) {
var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

output.appendChild(img);
}

function error() {
output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
}

output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```